# Creating a progressively enhanced form submission experience for clients with non-uniform JS/HTML5 support

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-enhancement, opera-mini

I'm a web developer and need help on enabling [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

**Background:**
I'm dealing with a web app where many users originate from a forward proxy that strips out JS.

Moreover, some users also use browsers that don't support HTML5, or browsers that can't run JS conventionally (e.g. Opera Mini).

Overall, HTML5 has more coverage than JS for this userbase.

**Current scenario:** Currently, this app uses no JS or HTML5 at all. Form submissions lead to full page refreshes. A typical form simply looks like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'submit_comment' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ my_form.comment }}
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

Ignore the `{{ }}` nomenclature. That's Django syntax and is simply used to render - in this case - a text field where a user can write a comment.

**The question:** For clients that can support JS or HTML5, how do I progressively enhance the form submission experience?

E.g., there's a section of this app where users leave comments for others to read. Currently, they press a 'reply' button and get redirected to a new page. The code for such a button is simply:

```
<form action="{% url 'response_page' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="{{ comment_id }}">
    <button type="submit">reply</button>
</form>
```

Now I need the following to happen:

1) If the client supports JS/HTML5, the DOM changes and a text field bound to a `form` appears right below the button. No refresh takes place.

2) If the client does not support JS/HTML5, the user is redirected to a new page as before.

---

How would one program this in a way that nothing breaks for unsupported users, and is as lightweight as possible? There's a lot of 'reply' buttons stacked together per page, so performance is critical as well.

I'm hoping there'd be established patterns to handle this kind of a thing. Being a web developer, I'm not privy to those. Would be great to get an illustrative answer.

---

*Note: I'd prefer to do it in HTML5, but open to JS solutions as well - and I prefer plain vanilla JS instead of anything fancier.*

Comment: Sorry if this is overly simple, but can't you just use event.preventDefault() in a event listener to overide the form action if javascript runs.

Comment: @iSZ: the answer will probably be simple. Could you write out a quick example of what you mean as an answer?

Comment: I think something like this. If the browsers are pre ie9 you'll probably have to add the onclick as an attribute instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic answer which prevents the form submission if javascript is available and adds the required input as suggested above.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type ='text';
  input.name = "comment";
  input.style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('myForm').appendChild(input);
  document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

```html
<form action="http://example.com" method="POST" aria-live="polite" id="myForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="">
  <button id="submit" type="submit">reply</button>
</form>
```

Comment: When `display:none` is set, that means the element never makes it to the render tree? Just looking at it from a performance angle as well.

Comment: You are correct, `display: none` is never in the render tree. It’s also not accessible to folks using screen readers, which seems to be the desired outcome.

On that note, however, it would probably make sense to announce the DOM change by hooking into `aria-live` for users of assistive tech. If you go that route, I’d also recommend maintaining the hidden DOM node in JS and only appending it when the AJAX-based submission has completed. You would want `aria-live` set on the parent container of the injected `div`.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the suggestions, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer iSZ. But it's slightly incomplete in terms of what I asked in the question. Before I mark it correct, instead of just appending basic text, could you instead append a basic form like I specified in the question? That way it'll be a complete answer (for me, and for future readers).

Comment: Moreover, is this kind of a thing possible in HTML5 at all, since many of my users are on a browser with a tenuous relationship with JS?

Comment: @Hassan From what I can make out, the HTML5 doctype triggers standards mode in pre html5 browsers. HTML5 input types also fallback to text, so I guess graceful degradation might be a better solution. As far as the example do you want to inject the whole form in rather than just progressively enhance it for ajax submissions?

Comment: @iSZ: just inject the form in for now, that'll be a wrap. Don't want to complicate it beyond tht.

Comment: Hey Hassan, I've added the form field below the button as suggested in one and stopped the submit. I didn't append the whole form as it would interfere with your template tags.